# Simple formula help

Tags: formula

[image]

Hi guys, for some reason I cannot wrap my head around the formula syntax, and I could use some help.  I understand this is a very easy and should be trivial.

My requirement is that IF `SAP Ship-to Account Number` IS NOT Null, `Override SAP` Address must be "Yes", and if It is Null it should be "No"`  Can anyone help me out with a simple formula? This was my initial logic in which I think I'm going the wrong way with it.

```
IF(AND(SAP_Ship_to_Account_Number__c = null),ISPICKVAL(Override__c,"Yes"),ISPICKVAL(Override__c, "No"))
```

> Update*
>
> I just realized that SAP Ship-to Account Number is a formula that concatenates 2 other fields.
>    That  will complicate things doesn't it..
>   I am getting the error
>
> Error: Formula result is data type (Text), incompatible with expected data type (true or false)

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `AND` and use `ISBLANK`. Also the 'Override SAP Address with Drop Ship Info' field should be a formula text field (not editable) if its based on the "Ship To Account Number:

`IF(ISBLANK(SAP_Ship_to_Account_Number__c),"Yes","No"))`

This might not work if you occasionally have to manually override the Override SAP address field

Comment: Oohh I like this idea, let me see if I can swing this

Comment: Also that formula doesn't work.  Says its missing a parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

```
IF(
AND(
  NOT(
     ISNULL(SAP_Ship_to_Account_Number__c)
  ),
  ISPICKVAL(Override__c,"Yes")
),
"Yes","No"
)
```

Comment: Missing a parenthesis some where, thanks for the quick response though